# How to control exposure time

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am trying to control exposure time but with no luck.

I have seen that it is not possible whit android.

How does FV-5 app control exposure time?

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978095/android-camera-api-iso-setting

Comment: I need to set or get the exposure time (not from EXIF) and not the ISO.

Answer (score 1):

FV-5 grabs images from the preview of the camera and accumulates them in software. See their [FAQ](http://www.camerafv5.com/faq.php#long-exposure-resolution).