# android camera ISO setting

Tags: android, android-camera

Is it possible to retrieve and change android camera setting ISO? I was able to do it on one device (HTC One) as explained in the below link using "iso-values" and "iso" keys.

[Android Camera API ISO Setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978095/android-camera-api-iso-setting)

However, it doesn't work on all the devices. Isn't it supported on all the android devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. Sorry, not my fault.

See https://www.google.co.il/search?q=site%3Aandroidfragmentation.com+-iso+preview  for a list of just a few devices that don't support ISO settings.

The others may have different settings that control ISO. Again, http://androidfragmentation.com is an invaluable resource.