# How to set ISO in Android Camera API setting?

Tags: android

I am working on camera app where i have to set the ISO but i could not get any method to set ISO like setPictureSize etc. Please let me know how do i know that device camera support ISO setting or not.

Thanks in Adavance.

Comment: you can check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37567225/3976589. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do that

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.set("iso", "400");
camera.setParameters(params);
```

The possible values are:

> 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, auto

To check if ISO is available on your device you may try this:

```
String supportedValues = camParams.get("iso-values");

if (supportedValues == null) {
    // ISO is not supported
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but how to does camera support ISO or not?

Comment: I agree with your answer @user3249477 but key "ISO-Values" is changed device to device