# Android camera2: capture request keys don't include settings I can control from the default app

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm using `getAvailableCaptureRequestKeys()` to know which settings I can modify.

For instance, say I want to modify the ISO. First I get all the available keys:

```
                        captureRequestKeys = cameraCharact.getAvailableCaptureRequestKeys();
```

Then I proceed to set the ISO to the value I want, only if the relevant key (`CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` in this case) is contained in `captureRequestKeys`.

```
if (captureRequestKeys.contains(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY))             
            captReqBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, MAX_ISO);
```

Whether the key is contained in `captureRequestKeys` depends on the terminal; in particular `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` is guaranteed to be present only for terminals that report being `HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL`, as pointed out by the documentation. Since my testing terminal is a `LEGACY` terminal, it does not surprise me that I cannot set the ISO.

What bothers me though is that I can do it just fine whenever I use the default camera app to take a picture. So my question is this: why can I set the ISO when I'm taking a picture with the default camera app, but I can't do that programmatically using the camera2 API? Am I missing something?

Same argument applies to the exposure time, since I can change that using the app just fine, but the key is not available. Is the app only giving the impression of changing those settings while in reality it is achieving the desired effect through other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I came to the conclusion that the stock camera app is using the old camera api. Indeed, if use `Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();` and then I print the string obtained using `parameters.flatten()`, iso control is among the parameters that I can change. Consequently, for those terminals which report being `LEGACY` using the camera2 method `cameraCharact.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)` I decided to revert back to the old camera api and to use the solution provided in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978095/android-camera-api-iso-setting) to manually set the iso.